# Will the HTC Desire HD have superior hardware than the Samsung Galaxy S?

Tags: hardware

I'm thinking about ditching my iPhone and going Android, so far the best contenders are the HTC Desire HD and the Samsung, which one has superior hardware specifications?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It really depends what you mean by superior. The Desire HD will be basically the same as the existing Desire but with a 4.3" screen and will have the same amount of internal storage as the Galaxy S.

The Desire HD will have 768 MB of RAM instead of 512 MB on the Galaxy S.

But the Desire HD will have the same Snapdragon processor as the old Desire, whereas the Galaxy S has the superior Hummingbird.

However, the Desire HD will have a 8 MP camera whereas the Galaxy S only has 5 MP, and the Desire HD has dual LED camera flash whereas some of the Galaxy S phones don't have a flash at all.

That sums up the major differences, and personally I'd lean toward the Desire HD, but you should compare for yourself and see what better fits your needs:

- [HTC Desire HD specifications](http://www.htc.com/www/product/desirehd/specification.html)
- [Samsung Galaxy S specifications](http://www.phonearena.com/htmls/Samsung-Galaxy-S-phone-p_4522.html)

Comment: In addition to you excellent answer I can add that the GPU on Galaxy S is superior than the one mounted on Desire HD, so if you main goal is gaming could make some difference.

Comment: Actually with the new Adreno 205 GPU which is on par with the one in the Galaxy S and along with the faster CPU, the Desire HD should be as fast if not faster.

Comment: In fact the Desire HD also has a better CPU than the Desire (Snapdragon QSD8250 vs Snapdragon MSM8255). In the end the combination of the better CPU plus the (way) better GPU than the Desire, the Desire HD becomes quite as fast as the Galaxy S.

Answer (score 3):

I chose the Desire HD over the Galaxy for a couple of fairly qualitative unscientific reasons.

1. I've had good experience with other HTC android phones (I adored my HTC magic).
2. To my eyes at least, the Samsung Galaxy has been styled to look just like an iPhone 3g. If I wanted something that looked like an iPhone, I'd get an iPhone.

On a more scientific level. As has been mentioned, while the Desire HD is still clocked at 1Ghz, it's snapdragon is the latest revision, made with the smaller process than the old Desire, and with the improved graphics. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snapdragon_%28processor%29

The screen on the desire is also bigger (and to my eyes awesome), but most reviews I've read say the colour and sharpness of the Galaxy is better. The Desire HD is also a big package overall, it may be a little too large for some pockets, I don't know how much more comact (if any) the galaxy is.

Comment: +1 At last someone agrees with me. I spent the best part of a week trying to work out whether I REALLY wanted the Galaxy S (this was months before Desire HD) amazing phone, amazing hardware, but the guy that designed the look and shape of the outside of the phone needs to be taken outside and shot! Sure, it looks great, but only because the designer of the iPhone 3G did a great job. The number of people who think I have an iPhone at first glance really p's me off!